# No funciona la validación por javascript en formulario

Tags: javascript, html, mvc, formularios, xampp

tengo un problema con mi formulario, al darle en submit no me valida los inputs que he puesto, al principio si lo hacia así no haya modificado ningún campo y todo chevere se mostraba la alerta, ahora solo si selecciono una imagen me realiza todas las validaciones. Utilizo apache en Xampp, a continuación el código:

**Utilizando Arquitectura MVC.**

La etiqueta script se encuentra colocada en el head dentro de header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/validations.js"></script>
```

Código de la vista del form en el archivo imageUploadView.php:

```
<title>Subir Imagen</title>
<form action="index.php?c=image&a=guardar" onsubmit="return validarCampos()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadImage">  
    <div class="form-group">  
        <label>Titulo: </label>  
        <input type="text" name="titulo"/><br>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Autor: </label>
        <input type="text" name="autor"/><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Formato: </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="formato" value="vertical"/>  Vertical<br>
        <input type="radio" name="formato" value="horizontal"/>  Horizontal<br>
        <input type="radio" name="formato" value="cuadrado"/>  Cuadrado
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tags: </label>
        <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Ej: escudo,dibujo,salud"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="image_fl"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar"/>
    <input type="reset" name="Limpiar" value="Limpiar"/>
</form>
```

Código javascript en el archivo validations.js:

```
function validarCampos(){
    var txtTitulo=document.querySelector("input[name='titulo']");
    var txtAutor=document.querySelector("input[name='autor']");
    var radiosFormato=document.querySelectorAll("input[name='formato']");
    var txtTags=document.querySelector("input[name='tags']");
    var flImage=document.querySelector("input[name='image_fl']");

    var alphareg = /^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g;
    var alphareg2 = /^[A-Za-z\_\-\.\s\xF1\xD1]+$/g;

    var valor;
    var resul=true;
    var mensaje="Campos inválidos, verificar:\n";

    valor=txtTitulo.value;
    if(valor.length===0 || valor.length<2 || valor.length>30
       || !valor.match(alphareg)){
       mensaje+= "\n El título no es correcto";
       resul=false;
    } 

    valor=txtAutor.value;
    if(valor.length===0 || valor.length<2 || valor.length>30
       || !valor.match(alphareg2)){
       mensaje+= "\n El autor no es correcto";
       resul=false;
    }

    var slc=false;
    for(i=0;i<radiosFormato.length;i++){
        if(radiosFormato[i].checked){
            slc=true;
        }
    }
    if(!slc){
        mensaje+="\n Seleccione un formato.";
        resul=false;
    }

    var filePath=flImage.value;
    var allowedExtensions= /(.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.ico)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        mensaje+="\n Formato de archivo no permitido";
        resul=false;
    }

    if(flImage.files[0]!=null){
        var fileSize=flImage.files[0].size;
        var maxSize=6*1024*1024; //6Mb
        if(fileSize>maxSize){
            mensaje+="\n Tamaño de imagen excesivo. (Max. 6Mb)";
            resul=false;
        }
    }

    if(!resul){
        alert(mensaje);
    }

    return resul;
}
```

Código del controlador en ImageController.php:

```php
public function guardar(){
        $img=new Image();
        $img->setImg_titulo($_REQUEST['titulo']);
        $img->setImg_autor($_REQUEST['autor']);
        $img->setImg_formato($_REQUEST['formato']);
        $img->setImg_tags($_REQUEST['tags']);
        $ruta="imageFiles/".trim($_REQUEST['titulo']).$this->typeImage();
        $ruta=str_replace(" ", "", $ruta);
        $img->setImg_ruta($ruta);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_fl"]["tmp_name"], $ruta)){
            echo $_FILES["image_fl"]["type"];
            //echo "Archivo guardado";
            $this->imageDao->insertar($img);
        }else{
            echo "Error al guardar el archivo en el servidor";
        }
        $this->buscar();

    }
```

Código del método que ejecuta la sentencia SQL dentro de ImageDAO.php:

```
public function insertar(Image $img){
        $sentencia=$this->conexion->prepare("insert into image (img_titulo,img_autor,img_formato,img_tags,img_ruta) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        $parametros=array($img->getImg_titulo(),$img->getImg_autor(),$img->getImg_formato(),$img->getImg_tags(),$img->getImg_ruta());
        $sentencia->execute($parametros);
    }
```

Error al darle a submit, aparece por un instante:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error que se muestra después:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente no logro descubrir el error, púes una validación parecida tengo dentro de otro proyecto y si funciona, lo único diferente entre ellos es el input de tipo file y sus correspondientes validaciones.

De antemano, gracias por la atención.

Comment: El error del `Cannot read propiety 'size' of undefined'` se resuelve colocando el `if(...)` como esta en la respuesta, parece que aun no esta agregado.

Comment: Disculpa, si lo había puesto pero lo saque de nuevo probando otras opciones.

Comment: Seria bueno ver el error que sale con esa linea agregada

Comment: Claro, sería lo adecuado, gracias por la recomendación, ya lo agregué.

Comment: aun con esa linea sigue el error de `Cannot read propiety 'size' of undefined'` ?

Comment: Si, solo hay cambio de la linea 21 a la 24 del error.